# Length of a single sublist in python

Tags: python, list, sublist

Lets assume i have a list of 3 sublists

```
a = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
```

If I use the command `len(a[0:2])` 
I get the answer 2 (Because there are two elements(sublists) in the list)

But when I do `len(a[2])` and want to get the answer 1 (because there is only one element(sublist) in the list) I actually get the length of the third list (which is 3 in this case).

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: How about `len(a[2:3])`?

Comment: `len(a[2])` takes the length of the third element. `len(a[0:2])` takes the number of elements in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `len(a[2:3])`:

```
 a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

a[2]
>>> [7, 8, 9] 

len(a[2])
>>> 3

a[2:3]
>>> [[7, 8, 9]] 

len(a[2:3])
>>> 1
```

Comment: Thank, that works perfectly! I thought that len(a[2:3]) would be out of the list range because the list doesn't have anything on index 3 but I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the range you want to look at.

`len(a[1:2])` should do the trick.

`len(a[x:y])` simply means "the length of a from element x to y (non-inclusive)"

So if you do `len(a[2:2])` the output is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
print(len(a[2:3]))
```

Or if want it builtin, do a function:

```
_len=len
def len(l):
    if _len(l)==0:
        return 0
    elif isinstance(l[0],list):
        return _len(l)
    return _len([l])

a=[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
print(len(a[2]))
```

Both Output:

```
1
```